# Why do I need thousands of dollars to convert to Judaism?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

Shalom. I'm a goy & I've been studying Torah for 4 years.

If a person wants to convert to Judaism, he has to move into a Jewish community. But in my country, I cannot afford doing that. Because Jews in my country live in an expensive city, bli ayin hara. And I cannot afford to move to the US, UK, or Israel. I don't speak Hebrew anyway, what am I going to do in E"Y?

For people who live in the Western hemisphere, converting is not expensive. But for people like us (who make 200-300 dollars a month, or 30-50 dollars in some cases), it's a fortune. For example, a guy from Hodu or Kush has access to the internet and he saw that Moshe is emes and his Torah is emes, and he doesn't wanna stay as a Noahide, he wants MORE than that. What is he going to do now? For example, a mehudar tefilin costs a couple thousand dollars. 5-7 thousand in some cases. Just because he doesn't have money, he won't be able to convert? But some people DO convert not for leshem shamayim, but for $$$ reasons or some other reasons. So what's the explanation? Hashem opened the doors for them and not for me? Why?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147179/discussion-on-question-by-fuggetaboutit-why-do-i-need-thousands-of-dollars-to-co); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.